# Variable out of Range

Tags: java, bluej

I have an error where line 61 states that variable `firstbattlerealactualhealth` is out of range to be used. I've tried various things, but I just can't seem to get it to work.

If you could show me what's wrong, and what I need to fix it, I'd be grateful.

**Edit:** changed which variable and line had a problem because I can't count or read.

```
boolean firstbattle = true;
while (firstbattle) {
    int firstbattlehealth = HP;
    int firstbattleattack = Attack;
    int firstbattledefense = Defense;
    int firstbattleMP = MP;
    int firstbattleEXP = EXP;
    int firstbattlegold = Gold;

    int firstattack = (int) Math.ceil(Math.random() * 6);
    int firstdefense = (int) Math.ceil(Math.random() * 6);

    int firstenemyattack = (int) Math.ceil(Math.random() * 6);
    int firstenemydefense = (int) Math.ceil(Math.random() * 6);

    int firstenemyhealth = firstenemyfirsthealth;

    int firstenemynewhealth = firstenemyfirsthealth;

    int firstenemyhitpoints = (int) Math.ceil(Math.random() * 25);

    int firsthitpoints = 0;
    boolean firstkill = true;
    while (firstkill) {
        if (firstattack > firstenemydefense) {
            firsthitpoints = (int) Math.ceil(Math.random() * firstbattleattack);
            System.out.println();
            System.out.println("You did " + firsthitpoints + " damge to the Slime.");           
        }

        firstenemynewhealth = firstenemyhealth - firsthitpoints;

        if (firstenemynewhealth <= 0) {
           firstkill = false;
        }

        if (firstattack <= firstenemydefense) {
            System.out.println();
            System.out.println("Attack failed!");
        }
        int firstbattleactualhealth = firstbattlehealth;
        if (firstenemyattack > firstdefense) {
            int firstenemyhitpointattack = (int) Math.ceil(Math.random() * firstenemyhitpoints);
            int firstbattlerealactualhealth = firstbattleactualhealth - firstenemyhitpointattack;
            System.out.println();
            System.out.println("The enemy did " + firstenemyhitpointattack + " damage to you. You have " + firstbattlerealactualhealth + " health remaining.");
        }

        if (firstenemyattack <= firstdefense ) {
            System.out.println();
            System.out.println("Enemy attack missed!");
        }
    }

    int firstenemyactualhealth = firstenemynewhealth;
    if (firstenemyactualhealth <= 0){
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("You won the battle!");

        HP = firstbattlerealactualhealth;
        EXP =  firstbattleEXP + 20;
        Gold = firstbattlegold + 20;
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("You have " + HP + " health.");
        System.out.println("You have earned" + EXP + " experience.");
        System.out.println("You have earned" + Gold + " gold.");

        firstbattle = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Where does `firstenemyfirsthealth` come from?

Comment: Sorry, folks, I messed up in what I was looking for. It's actually line 61, and variable "firstbattlerealactualhealth", where it is supposed to equal variable "HP". It first shows up in line 44, where it is equal to the health being taken away by the monster.

Comment: so error occurs at `HP = firstbattlerealactualhealth;`? if that's the case, perhaps you should just write that in your question

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's probably because `firstbattlerealactualhealth` is defined inside an `if` clause. If the program does not execute that `if` block, `firstbattlerealactualhealth` will not be defined. You have to define & initialize it somewhere that you are sure it will be executed.

Bottom line, if you define a variable inside a block(`{}`), it should *only* be used inside of that block, and nowhere else.

*tips:*

Don't name any of the variables `first_sth`. It will most necessarily be followed by variables with names `second_sth` and `third_sth` and you will not be able to manage them. You should reuse that same logic for other battles (not only slimes) by passing different parameters, and that way you can write DRY(Don't repeat yourself) code. The variable names will also be much readable.

Comment: Thanks. This is perhaps the third time today that I've done this, I'll keep this in mind.